# AngularJS nesting elements with multidimensional arrays and displaying them with a click

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

Here is the fiddle that accurately displays information but is visually not correctly positioned.

http://jsfiddle.net/LhRfq/

My scope is a three dimensional json object.

The first level array items are supposed to be displayed in a single line and that works just fine..

The second layer of selected sub array data is displayed also in a line when top array item is checked.

Using the same approach I am perfectly able to display the third layer as well, however what I need to happen for the third layer is to display sub items directly below a belonging array item..

The below code is close to what I need but I can't seem to isolate the sub array items that I need only for the selected element.. or more precisely, only selected sub array displays multiple times instead of once...

This is my current code

```
<div ng-repeat="publication in publicationData">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pubCat" ng-model="publication.selected">
            {{publication.pubName}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<br/><br/>


<div ng-repeat="publication in publicationData | filter:{selected:true}" >
    <div>
        <ul id="publists">
            <li ng-repeat="category in publication.pubCat">
                <input type="checkbox" name="pubCat" ng-model="category.selected">{{category.pubCatName}}



                <!-- THIS CODE DISPLAYS THE SAME ARRAY MULTIPLE TIMES -->

                <div ng-repeat="publication in publicationData">
                <div ng-repeat="category in publication.pubCat | filter:{selected:true}">

                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="subcategory in category.pubSubCat">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="pubSubCat">{{subcategory.pubSubCatName}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                </div>  
                </div>

                <!-- ABOVE CODE DISPLAYS THE SAME ARRAY MULTIPLE TIMES -->



            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

I do understand why this is happening but I don't quote understand how I could accomplish what I need to see.

What would you advise as the approach to accomplish something that looks like this... if in the first array "Option 1" is checked and in second "SubOpt 1 B" is checked

```
|_| Option 1          |_| Option 2          |_| Option 3

|_| SubOpt 1 A        |_| SubOpt 1 B        |_| SubOpt 1 C

                    |_| SubSubOptB 1    
                    |_| SubSubOptB 2     
                    |_| SubSubOptB 3    
                    |_| SubSubOptB 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve this by nesting ng-repeat of second dimension of json array into ng-repeat of the first dimension of json array.. also by nesting third into second. The trick was to repeat the declaration of the ng-repeat in separate elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you try to create dynamic gap (aka `margin-left`).

You can achieve that by using `ng-style` that has ability to dynamically change style:

```
<div ng-repeat="publication in publicationData" ng-style="myStyle($index)">
```

and in controller:

```
 $scope.myStyle = function(index) {
        return {
            "margin-left": (93 * index) + "px" // example only
        }
    };
```

This is direction,

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LhRfq/2/)**</kbd>

hope it will help you

Comment: Um, I know I am not explaining myself quite right. Your suggestion is not what I am looking for but I might look into ng-style and apply it to what I need somehow. What I want is to list the third layer of my array under each belonging item of the second layer only when the relevant check box is checked. I am nit by the machine but I will do a fiddle that produces the visual of what I need as soon as I am in the office. Either way, thanks :) If I delve deeper into your idea I may figure it out.